# $(object).css('background-color','red' not working

Tags: css

I have a modal form that accepts an email address.  I then validate this and want to highlight the email box if invalid.  But using .css('background-color','red') doesn't do anything.  I've tried camel case'backgroundColor' but that didn't make any difference.  The code is going through the else path 'cos I'm getting the alert.  Here's the code:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Send": function() {

                if (validateEmail($('#email').val()))
                {
                var datastr = 'name=' + $('#name').val() + '&email=' + $('#email').val() + '&enquiry=' + $('#enquiry').val() + '&recip=' + eMail;

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "email.php",
                data: datastr,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                        alert ("Email has been Sent");
                        }
                });

                $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                }
                else
                {
                $('#email').css('background-color','red');
                alert('Your Email Address is invalid');
                }
             },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
             }},
        close: function() {
           $( this ).dialog('destroy');
        }
    });
```

And the form here:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Contact Computer Rep" style="display: none">
<form>
    <div tal:condition="data/userlevel"><span>Your Name:</span><span tal:content="data/displayname"></span><br />
        <span>Your Email Address:</span><span tal:content="data/mail"></span>
    </div>
<fieldset>
    <span tal:condition="not: data/userlevel">
    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="email">Your Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    </span>
    <label for="enquiry">Your Enquiry</label>
    <input type="text" name="enquiry" id="enquiry" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that $('#email') actually resolves to something? Please post your html markup!

Comment: Well... it should work. Once nothing changed - try to check if there is no styles overloading your value and check if `$('#email')` finds something at all (`$('#email').length != 0`). Also, are your else branch executed at all?

Comment: I know $('#email') resolves to something because an invalid email fires the alert...

Comment: Ah got it!  Removed the class ui-widget-content and it now works, although I don't quite understand why this was blocking things?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery understands both `background-color` and `backgroundColor`. Try using a RGB value instead of `red` such as:

```
$('#email').css('background-color', '#f00');
```

Comment: this didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate that email is the id of your email box.
you can also try putting `$('#email').css({'background-color': 'red'});`

Comment: Also check that no other style is overriding the email box style.